# Issue with Oracle regex

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

```
select regexp_substr('select count(distinct empno), count(distinct deptno) from emp',
                     'count\(distinct.*\)')
  from dual;
```

For the above query I want output `count(distinct empno)`, but the ".*" in the above query is taking the last occurrence of ")" and not the first occurrence.

Can anyone please tell how to get the output I want?

Comment: Use the non greedy expression, `.*?` instead of `.*`

Comment: I donno why the same answers.

Answer (score 4):

[The `*` operator is 'greedy' by default](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_regexp.htm#CHDIDJJC). You're allowing any characters between `distinct` and `)`, in any quantity. and including the first `)` itself.

As EatÅPeach suggested, you can make it non-greedy with `?`:

> A greedy operator matches as many occurrences as possible while allowing the rest of the match to succeed. To make the operator nongreedy, follow it with the nongreedy modifier (?)

So here, with `.*?` instead of `.*`:

```
select regexp_substr(
  'select count(distinct empno), count(distinct deptno) from emp',
    'count\(distinct.*?\)')
from dual;
```

Or you can specify it should be any character except `)` with `[^)]*` instead of `.*`.

```
select regexp_substr(
  'select count(distinct empno), count(distinct deptno) from emp',
    'count\(distinct[^)]*\)')
from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.*`, use `[^)]*`:

```
select regexp_substr('select count(distinct empno), count(distinct deptno) from emp',
                     'count\(distinct[^)]*\)')
from dual;
```

However, I'm surprised that this is necessary.  I would expect the expression to return the first closing paren.

Comment: Why are you surprised that this is necessary? `.*` matches any character besides newlines by default and the `*` quantifier means it will try to match as much as possible (greedy).

Comment: @Jerry . . . I didn't realize that it defaulted to greedy in Oracle.  This may not be consistent with other regular expression implementations.

Comment: Well, AFAIK, it's defaults to greedy in most implementations. I actually can't remember the last time I came across an implementation where it defaulted to lazy.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for "any char except ')'" instead of "any char", as in the following:

```
select regexp_substr('select count(distinct empno), count(distinct deptno) from emp',
                 'count\(distinct [^\)]*\)') from dual;
```