# oracle regexp_substr to fetch string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql

I have a sql query like

> select count(distinct empno), count(distinct(deptno empname empid )) from emp

I want to fetch first occurrence of count and its content like:

> count(distinct empno)

I have tried the following sql statement but its not working,

> SQL >select regexp_substr('select count(distinct empno),
>   count(distinct(deptno)) from emp',     'count *( *distinct .*)')
>   from dual ;
>
> REGEXP_SUBSTR('SELECTCOUNT(DISTINCTEMPNO),COUN
>   ---------------------------------------------- count(distinct empno), count(distinct(deptno ))

I want output to return like :

> > REGEXP_SUBSTR('SELECTCOUNT(DISTINCTEMPNO)
> >
> > count(distinct empno),

Regular expression should not match second ) closing bracket and it should match the  1st closing bracket.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue with Oracle regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431931/issue-with-oracle-regex)

Answer (score 0):

`*` in your regex ates everything, you need to make the regex engine to match the shortest possibility.

```
count *\([^\)]\)(?=,)
```